# nodejs can´t handle http successfully responses due to (probably) high volume of promises - Growth problems

Tags: node.js, express, promise, axios, event-loop

I am finding my self blind on how to understand the root cause of this problem. Any direction is very welcomed
I´ve made some tests as well which I am going to show here

A) --- General Scenery -----

I have two cluster on `GCP`
`Scheduler` (2-15 servers) and `Consumer` (6-100) servers
`Scheduler` gets the tasks that need to be done and send it to the `Consumer`.

There are about 2.2K messages per minute from `Scheduler` to `Consumer` and as more `Schedulers` are created, more the tasks are divided among them.

The problem:

1. `Consumer` process 100% of the requests bellow 3 seconds
2. About 0.5% of the cases, `Scheduler` logs shows a `timeout` even if the `Consumer` has processed the request in <2 seconds. I am sure because each request has an unique ID.
3. `Axios` timeout are set to 20 seconds
4. When the errors are logged in `Scheduler`, the elapsed time from the beginning of the request until the exception **handling is about 45 seconds** . So way more than the 20s Axios expiring time.
5. Being at Google GCP local network means, as a premise, that I have no problem in network
6. `Scheduler` CPU is rising but not necessarily overwhelmed, i.e, less than 80%
   `Scheduler` will get up to 100 tasks and process them 15 at a time (`Promise.all`()) and wait for the responses, than the next 15 and so on

What this scenery suggests to me is that `Scheduler` `nodejs` is not being able to process the responses that `Consumers` replies it and somehow it is missing some replies.

**So, the hypothesis goes like this:**

`Scheduler` is able to send a high volume of messages but unable to get the results because `Axios` timeout will expire before the `eventloop` is able to tackle the 200 response from the Consumer.

B) ------ The Tests ------

We could reproduce the problem in the tests. We've created a sender and a receiver. sender just send an incremental number to receiver, 100 at a time, 10000 times

There are several cases where receiver says it processed a specific task (number) but  sender is presenting a timeout.

[Here is sender and receiver](https://gist.github.com/nneutrinno/a8e565f432749830bab120ba41d30bc8)

Sender

```
import Aigle from 'aigle';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as _ from 'lodash';


async function main(): Promise<void> {
    const TIMEOUT: number = 1000;
    const LIMIT: number = 10000;
    const items: unknown[] = _.range(LIMIT)
    let REMOTE_MACHINE: string = ''
    const hash: { [key in string]: true } = {};


    if (!REMOTE_MACHINE) throw new Error('No remote mahchine')

    try {

        const out = await Aigle
            .resolve(items)
            .mapLimit(100, async (address, index) => {
                try {
                    const response = await axios.get(`http://${REMOTE_MACHINE}:4000/${index}`, { timeout: TIMEOUT })
                    print({ type: 'response', index })
                    // 
                    return response;
                } catch (err) {
                    hash[index] = true;
                    print({ type: 'err', index })
                    // 
                    return err
                }
            })
        ;

        console.log('Amount errors', Object.keys(hash).length)

        await axios.get(`http://${REMOTE_MACHINE}:4000/${LIMIT}`, { timeout: TIMEOUT })
        // 
    } catch (err) {
        console.log({ err })
    }

    function print(item: any) {
        return console.log(item)
    }
    
}
main();
```

Receiver

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')


function main() {
        const app = express()
        let count = 0;
        const LIMIT = 10000;
        const hash = {}

app.get('/:num?', async (req, res) => {
            // if (req.params.num !== count.toString()) console.log(req.params.num)
            count++;
            hash[req.params.num] = true;
            if (Number(req.params.num) >= LIMIT) {
                    const difference = Array(LIMIT).fill(0).map((_, index) => index).filter((_, index) => !hash[index])

                    console.log({ difference });
                    fs.writeFileSync('out', JSON.stringify({ difference, hash }))
            }
            console.log({ count, body: req.params.num })
            res.send({ message: 'Out' });
        });
        app.listen(4000, () => console.log('listening'))
}

main()
```

So the questions are:

1. What could be the reasons scheduler falsely appoint a timeout
2. Is there a safe parallelism threshold that we must respect? Is it bind to parallel process and/or IO?
3. Any pattern I should use?

Comment: I think its unlikely anyone can help you very specifically without seeing and understanding actual code and actual timing of requests and understanding how many simultaneous requests are in flight at once.  You could be timing out because your server is overloaded or you could  be exhausting resources on either client or server by trying to do too many things at once.

Comment: Please include relevant portions of your code IN your question pasted in as text, not only as an external link.  This is for a variety of reasons, including search indexing, the fact that external links change or disappear over time rendering the question useless as a long term resource, etc...